# calculate remaining time in hour second and minutes between two date with moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have two dates

```
State: 2014-06-10T08:32:33Z
End: 2014-07-11T08:32:33Z
```

I want to calculate the remaining time in Hours, Seconds and Minutes with Moment. How is it possible?

The following example http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/gtKeL/ return output like `'a month ago'..What changes it will require? Please suggest`

Comment: Show your code plz :)

Comment: oops, forgot to add. Please check the updated one.

Comment: Do you mean you want a string '744 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds'?

Comment: It can be something like 2 days 12:20:20 left

Answer (score 0):

Without moment.js it can be done with a fairly simple function:

```
// Where this = time value in milliseconds
function msToHMS(ms) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n;}
  var sign = ms < 0? '-' : '';
  ms = Math.abs(ms);
  return sign + z(ms/3.6e6|0) + ':' + z(ms%3.6e6/6e4|0) + ':' + z(ms%6e4/1e3|0);
}

console.log(msToHMS(Date.UTC(2014,5,10,8,32,33) - Date.UTC(2014,6,11,8,32,33))); // -744:00:00
```

It's much better to post your code here than some remote site.